# SEM/Bayesnets: does creating a latent variable always reduce the fit?

Tags: bayesian, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, confirmatory-factor

assume there are 3 variables (x1, x2, x3) that each correlate tightly with each other, and also correlate tightly with y.

if we add a latent/hidden variable that merges information from x1, x2 and x3 and connect it to y, will the correlation between LV and Y always be less than or equal to the correlation of X1 to Y, X2 to Y, or X3 to Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Removing measurement error can definitely produce larger correlations. Here's an example:

```
X1 <- c(1,6,7,6,7)
X2 <- c(6,7,6,7,6)
X3 <- c(2,6,7,6,7)
Y  <- c(7,7,6,7,6)
```

The first item has more noise than the others. The LV equation would take this into account, which should produce a bigger correlation coefficient.

Also, you seem to have conflated "fit" with measures of association. The latter describes the strength of a relationship (like a correlation coefficient). The former describes differences between models (e.g., misfit of observed compared to theoretical model).

You can therefore have varying degrees of "fit" and that's completely unrelated to the size of a correlation.